# worksheets/key/public/full service requires NID cookie starting from 30.04.2019

Tags: google-sheets-api

Starting from 30.04.2019 worksheets public/full API does not work without adding a NID cookie to request.
Example GET request to a sheet I just created: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/worksheets/1_QM2VCVaerfDlhTDgYpkSErEEv7IR0_452UIC1n_CC0/public/full

This request works if you send a google NID cookie and gives a HTTP 500 "Internal Error" otherwise. This used to work some days ago. As I don't have used cookies in my v3.0 API, I would like to keep things as they were.

The scope of my java application is to fetch data in read-only mode, no authentication / access restrictions are needed. Having an application-specific access key is not a desired result.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the changes in API?

Comment: I could not find any documentation for that change - it just magically happened overnight. And just as magically google fixed it, so the issue is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I was able to work around the problem by parsing the html from the pubhtml page directly to output a similar JSON format using some jQuery:

Instead of using the Google Sheet ID, use the link for "Publish to Webpage".

```
function importGoogleSheets(publishedUrl, sheetId, onSuccess, onError) {

        var headers = [];
        var rows;

        $.ajax({
            url: publishedUrl+'?gid='+sheetId+'&single=true',
            success: function(data) {
                data = $.parseHTML(data)[5];
                htmldata = data;
                rows = data.getElementsByTagName('tr');

                for (var i = 0; i < rows[1].cells.length; i++) {
                    headers[i] = 'gsx$' + rows[1].cells[i].textContent.toLowerCase().replace(/[^0-9a-z]*/g, '');
                }

                for (var i = 3; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    temp = {};
                    for (var h = 1; h < headers.length; h++) {
                        temp[headers[h]] = {'$t': rows[i].cells[h].textContent};
                    }
                    all_data[i - 3] = temp;
                }
                onSuccess(all_data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                onError(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

One note though is that this won't cut off empty rows, so you may want to filter the output.